# Two sqlalchemy queries return the same result even though they have different filters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have 2 classes: Foo and Bar. Assume that a Foo can have many Bars (via foo.Bars). Bar has an end_date to indicate when a bar has ended. Bars that have not ended are set to '9999-12-31' by default.

I've written two queries below to get a Foo but with different bar filters such that the first query gives me bars that have not ended; the second gives me bars that have ended.

```
   today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

   current = session.query(Foo)\
                        .join(Bar)\
                        .filter(
                            and_(
                                 Foo.code=='MY_STRING',
                                 Bar.end_date >= today,
                                 )
                        )\
                        .options(contains_eager('Bars'))\
                        .one()

   previous = session.query(Foo)\
                        .join(Bar)\
                        .filter(
                            and_(
                                 Foo.code=='MY_STRING',
                                 Bar.end_date < today,
                                 )
                        )\
                        .options(contains_eager('Bars'))\
                        .one()
```

For some reason previous.Bars are the same as current.Bars even though we've filtered the bars to be different (at least that was my attempt). E.g. `current.Bars` returns `[bar1, bar2, bar3]` and `previous.Bars` returns `[bar1, bar2, bar3]`.

If I switch the two queries (i.e. put `previous` before `current`), then current's Bars are the same as previous.Bars. E.g. current.Bars returns `[bar4, bar5, bar6]` and `previous.Bars` returns `[bar4, bar5, bar6]`.

Note that I'm 100% sure that the underlying data in previous.Bars should be different from current.Bars. I.e. I should get `[bar4, bar5, bar6]` for `previous.Bars` and `[bar1, bar2, bar3]` for `current.Bars`

Can someone please explain why I'm getting the same results? How can I solve this? I realize it's probably better just to have one query.

Thanks in advance!

PS I'm using version 0.8

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: @Drewness I'm using version 0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem line is `.options(contains_eager('Bars'))`. It basically tells `sqlachemy` that that query contains **all** `Bars` for each `foo` loaded. So when you access `foo.Bars`, it does not query the database anymore, because it has taken those (*filtered*) bars from the `join` and assumed them to be a full `foo.Bars` relationship.
The next time you run the query, sqlalchemy realizes that the object `Foo` is already loaded (including its relationship `Bars`) and basically returns what it currently has in the session (memory).

You can work-around this by removing the object from the session using `session.expunge(current)` just before you execute query for `previous`, so that `sqlalchemy` will reload it completely, but you have to be careful using `current` instance after that because it is not part of the session anymore.

**Better yet**: since you need both sides anyway, just do this separation on python side easily:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()#.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
foo = (session.query(Foo)
        .options(joinedload(Foo.Bars))
        .filter(Foo.code=='MY_STRING')
        .one()
        )
prev_bars = [bar for bar in foo.Bars if bar.end_date < today]
curr_bars = [bar for bar in foo.Bars if bar.end_date >=today]
print foo
print prev_bars
print curr_bars
```